# How to find out IRS notices on a topic?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs

Is there a way to find out IRS notices on a topic? I had a question about HSA and found my answer in [this](http://www.irs.gov/irb/2004-33_IRB/ar08.html) notice but since its more than 10 years old, I wonder if the information therein is current or not. Specifically are following answers correct even today?

> Q-69. If administration and account maintenance fees (e.g., flat
>   administrative fees) are withdrawn from the HSA, are the withdrawn
>   amounts treated as taxable distributions to the account beneficiary?
>
> A-69.  No.  Amounts withdrawn from an HSA for administration and
>   account maintenance fees will not be treated as a taxable distribution
>   and will not be included in the account beneficiary’s gross income.
>
> Q-70. If administration and account maintenance fees are withdrawn
>   from the HSA, does the withdrawn amount increase the maximum annual
>   HSA contribution limit?
>
> A-70. No.For example, if the maximum annual contribution limit is
>   $2,000, and a $25 administration fee is withdrawn from the HSA, the
>   annual contribution limit is still $2,000, not $2,025.
>
> Q-71.  If administration and account maintenance fees are paid by the
>   account beneficiary or employer directly to the trustee or custodian,
>   do these payments count toward the annual maximum contribution limit
>   for the HSA?
>
> A-71. No. Administration and account maintenance fees paid directly by
>   the account beneficiary or employer will not be considered
>   contributions to the HSA.  For example, an individual contributes the
>   maximum annual amount to his HSA of $2,000.   The account beneficiary
>   pays an annual administration fee of $25 directly to the trustee.  The
>   individual’s maximum annual contribution limit is not affected by the
>   payment of the administration fee.

Comment: The answers are still correct today, except the contribution limit amount listed in answers A-70 and A-71 are old.

Answer (score 1):

The IRS publishes the current information on their website:
http://apps.irs.gov/app/picklist/list/formsPublications.html